# What's the difference between LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, let

There was a similar question [Clarity on the difference between “LexicalEnvironment” and “VariableEnvironment” in ECMAScript/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031667/clarity-on-the-difference-between-lexicalenvironment-and-variableenvironment) posted on SO two years ago, but it was based on ES5.

I'm learning ES6 now and encountered some fun facts. For example, in a block scope, you can't declare one variable with `let` more than once.

```
// you can declare a variable with var multiple times
var a = 1;
var a = 2;
a;     // => 2

// but you can't do that with let
{
    let a = 1;
    let a = 2; // => Error
}
```

So I referred to the [ES6 draft](https://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts), and some sentences there caught my attention:

> **let** and **const** declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.
>
> A **var** statement declares variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s VariableEnvironment.

Well consider this:

```
// in global execution context
{
    let a = 1;
    var b = 2;
}
console.log(a);    // => ReferenceError: a is not defined
console.log(b);    // => 2
```

As we all know, the `let` declarations restrict the scope of variables in the block, but how should we understand the phrase `**let** and **const** declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.`?

Does the LexicalEnvironment here has something to do with the block?

Comment: [Here's a draft spec for ES6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#table-23), they're both pretty much defined the same as ES5, so the answers to the question you linked to should still mostly be valid?

Comment: Yep, the answer to the linked question is still valid in this case.